# Driver for Broadcom 14e4:43ba chip

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, macintosh, broadcom

I just got a Macbook Pro 12,1 which comes with the Broadcom `14e4:43ba` chip (output from `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`).

#### What I've tried

First, I built the latest kernel (4.1.6) from source.  According to [this page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211#brcmfmac), installing the `brcmfmac` driver should work for that chip.  I copied [brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin) to the `/etc/firmware/brcm` directory, then added `brcmfmac` to `/etc/modules`, rebooted, and verified both that 4.1.6 was running and that `brcmfmac` appeared in the output from `lsmod`.  However, wifi still seems not to work; `iwconfig` gives:

```
eth0: no wireless extensions
lo: no wireless extensions
```

How can I get this wifi chip working?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had failed to enable PCIE bus support for brcmfmac when compiling the Linux kernel.  To do so, run `make menuconfig` and navigate:

```
Device drivers
- Network device support
  - Wireless LAN
    - PCIE bus interface support for FullMAC driver
```

and enable PCIE bus support.